# accessing the 'ui' object in a jquery-ui event

Tags: jquery-ui

So I am trying to get the height of an autcomplete input when the open function fires. My code looks like this

```
 open: function(event, ui) {     
                $('#paddingDiv').css('height', '300px');
            },
```

I have tried looking for more information about how you access the object but keep just finding simple tutorials, nothing in the way "structure of the ui object in events" or something like that, I have tried various ways to get the height but nothing seems to work.

Where can I find more information about how to work with the ui object?

Comment: See: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open *Note: The `ui` object is empty but included for consistency with other events*

Comment: When are you trying to get the height? And of which element?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
$(this).autocomplete("widget").height();
```

> **widget()**
>
> Returns a `jQuery` object containing the menu element. Although the menu items are constantly created and destroyed, the menu element itself is created during initialization and is constantly reused.
>
> - This method does not accept any arguments.

Then use it like:

```
open: function(event, ui) {     
  $('#paddingDiv').css('height', '300px');
  console.log($(event.target).autocomplete("widget").height());
  // Not sure if $(this) = event.target
},
```